On Regular Epimorphisms in the category of Topological Spaces
Sorry for the silly doubt. It is well-known that:
a) quotient maps are the regular epimorphisms in the category of topological spaces and continuous functions. This implies that the regular quotient objects of $X$ bijectively correspond to the equivalence relations on $X$ (equipped with the quotient topology).
b) monomorphisms in the category of topological spaces and continuous functions are the continuous injective functions
My questions are:

Take then a regular epimorphism $f: X \to Y$. May I identify the topology on $Y$ (the image of $f$) with the final topology induced by $f$? In other terms, if $X$ is a topological space equipped with a topology (open sets!) $\mathcal{F}_X$ and $Y$ is a topological space equipped with a topology $\mathcal{F}_Y$, can I replace $\mathcal{F}_Y$ with the final topology induced by $f$? In view of the comment by ZhenLin, it seems that yes, I can. Did I understand correctly?

Now, let $g: X \to Y$ be any continuous function. I consider its $(RegularEpimorphism,Monomorphism)$-factorization $g=q \circ p$. Then $p: X \to Z$ is a regular epimorphism and $q$ is a monomorphism. Thus $p: (X,\mathcal{F}_X) \to (Z,\mathcal{F}_Z)$ and $q: (Z,\mathcal{F}_Z) \to (Y,\mathcal{F}_Y)$. I known that factorization are essentially unique and, moreover, I know the behavior of regular epimorphisms and of monomorphisms in the category of topological space. Up to isomorphisms, can I assume in the previous factorization that $Z=Im(g)$ and that $\mathcal{F}_Z$ is the final topology induced by $g$? If yes, in such a case, again up to isomorphism, can I also assume that $q: (Im(g),{\rm final \,\, topology \,\, induced \,\, by \,\, g}) \to (Y,\mathcal{F}_Y)$ is the inclusion map?



I am confused. You have an epimorphism. So the image (as a set) is Y. Why do you write im(f) then?

@MartinBrandenburg Very sorry for the confusion provoked. I suitably edited my question in order to avoid any confusion.

The quotient topology is the final topology induced by a surjective map, yes. Continuous maps have a ternary factorisation as a quotient map followed by a continuous bijection followed by an embedding. If what you really want to know is whether the category of topological spaces is a regular category, the answer is no, as the existence of non-invertible continuous bijections proves.

@ZhenLin This is not what I'm asking for. See the edits for an improved question

Q1. Yes. $f : X \to Y$ is defined to be a quotient map if it is a surjection such that $V \subset Y$ is open in $Y$ iff $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$. The latter means that the set $Y$ is endowed with the quotient topology induced by the surjection $f$. In this case it is the same as the final topology induced by $f$. Note, however, that the final topology is defined for any (not necessarily surejctive) function $f : X \to Y$. Only for surjective $f$ this topology is called quotient topology.
Q2. $(RegularEpimorphism,Monomorphism)$ is indeed a factorization structure on the category $\mathbf{Top}$ of toplogical spaces and continous maps. I guess you know the concept of a factorization structure; see for example
Chapter IV in

Jiří Adámek, Horst Herrlich, George Strecker. Abstract and concrete categories. Wiley-Interscience 1990

For each map $g : X \to Y$ you get a factorization $g = q \circ p$ with a regular epimorphism (= quotient map) $p : (X,\mathcal F_X) \to (Z,\mathcal F_Z)$ and a monomorphism (= injection) $q : (Z,\mathcal F_Z) \to (Y,\mathcal F_Y)$  by taking

$Z = g(X) \subset Y$ endowed with the quotient topology $\mathcal F_Z$ induced by the surjecton $g' : X \xrightarrow{g} g(X) = Z$,
$q$ = inclusion $g(X) \hookrightarrow Y$.

On the level of sets we obviously have $g = q \circ p$, but in general $\mathcal F_Z$ does not agree with the subspace topology induced on $g(X)$ by $\mathcal F_Y$, thus the "non-trivial" part is to check that  $q : (Z,\mathcal F_Z) \to (Y,\mathcal F_Y)$ is continuous. This means that $V \in \mathcal F_Y$ implies that $q^{-1}(V) = V \cap g(X) \in \mathcal F_Z$. But $p^{-1}(q^{-1}(V)) = g^{-1}(V) \in \mathcal F_X $ so that $q^{-1}(V) \in \mathcal F_Z$ since $Z$ has the quotient topology.
So yes, you can assume that $Z=Im(g)$ and that $\mathcal{F}_Z$ is the final topology induced by $g$. I think, however, that writing $Z = Im(g)$ is misleading when working with topological spaces. The image of $g$ with respect to the factorization structure  $(RegularEpimorphism,Monomorphism)$ should be regarded as the morphism $p : (X,\mathcal F_X) \to (Z,\mathcal F_Z)$  defined above.

Thank you for you answer! Yeah, I know that $Z=Im(g)$ is misleading in a categorical setting, I meant actually the set-theoretical image of $g$, so I too was unsure about the notation to use. Hence, based on your answer, as per the final part of my question, it seems clear to me that I can also assume that $q: (Im(g),\text{final topology induced by g}) \to (Y,\mathcal{F}_Y)$ is the inclusion map. Thank you again!
